# Using directive to specify class alias in C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli, using-directives

In C#, there are three types of using directives:

```
using System; // Specify Namespace
using Diag = System.Diagnostics; // Specify Namespace Alias
using DBG = System.Diagnostics.Debug;  // Specify Class Alias
```

In C++/CLI, I know the equivalents to the first two:

```
using namespace System;
namespace Diag = System::Diagnostics;
```

Is there any way to do the third one in C++/CLI?

Doing `namespace DBG = System::Diagnostics::Debug;` gives `error C2879: 'System::Diagnostics::Debug' : only an existing namespace can be given an alternative name by a namespace alias definition`

The only alterntive I've come up with is `#define DBG System::Diagnostics::Debug`, but I'd prefer a proper using directive, if available.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A C++ typedef will do the trick here.

```
typedef System::Diagnostics::Debug DBG;
```