# Alias for "System::Collections::Generic::IList" in c++ cli

Tags: c++-cli, alias

I am working with c++ cli.

Writing "System::Collections::Generic::IList" for IList every time is difficult, makes code long and difficult to read.

It is dicussed here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328149/using-directive-to-specify-class-alias-in-c-cli)

```
using IList = System::Collections::Generic::IList; // Didn't work.
typedef System::Collections::Generic::IList Ilist; // Didn't work also.
```

How can I make alias for it?

Comment: A typedef works fine.  But this is a generic type, you have to nail down the type parameters to name the concrete type.  So, say, `typedef System::Collections::Generic::IList<int> mylist;`.  You could write a template to supply the type argument, but they don't behave well in metadata.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't include `using namespace System::Collections::Generic;` at the top of the code file?

Comment: I already have that line on top my code. But it doesn’t work either. Do you have a code which works in that way? My be I am doing something wrong.

Comment: If you can't pay attention to the details, you are going to face a lot of frustration as a software developer. Note the difference in the line you have in your question with the using directive that I showed you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sitting at a compiler, but I'm guessing that the typedef doesn't work because `IList` isn't the full name of that type: The full name would be `IList<some type>`. You should be able to do
`typedef System::Collections::Generic::IList<String^> IStringList;`.

Since it doesn't look like you want to change the name of `IList` to something else, `using namespace System::Collections::Generic;` should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

The code below compiled. But that is not what i am looking for. type in angle brackets can be integer, string or any class list. But in some context it works.

```
typedef System::Collections::Generic::IList<int>^ IintList1;
using IintList2 = System::Collections::Generic::IList<int>^;

IintList1 list1 = nullptr;
list1->Add(1);
IintList2 list2 = nullptr;
list2->Add(2);
```